# Target multiple programming languages/platforms

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, cross-platform

Are there any good ways to define interfaces/class hierarchies in a non language specific fashion and then generate corresponding source code in specified languages? In particular, I need to target both Java and C# for a fairly comprehensive API I am creating. I recall at one point seeing a post here on SF where an answer mentioned a programming language that 'compiled' to other languages-- but I have not been able to find the post. That language may be a solution for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/blog/category/Wasabi.aspx :-P

Comment: That looks neat, but it isn't the language that I saw previously on SF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language)? It's easy to find code-generators from UML for lots of different languages (Eg. [this one](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-code-generation.html) can generate C#, Java and VB.NET code), but you might want to carefully evaluate if it's the right choice for you. As a standard, it has come in for substantial [criticism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812680/what-are-the-most-significant-disadvantages-of-using-uml) over the years.

Comment: I was considering using UML as I already have access to a number of UML tools. I was kind of hoping that someone would suggest something that allows for some basic code generation insofar as Java and C# have common constructs and basic libraries.

Comment: My favorite free, open source, tool for UML is ArgoUML (http://argouml.tigris.org/) it can generate code for Java and C# with the right plugins. It also has critiques to help users make better UML diagrams.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of ways of doing something like what you want.

For example you could look at using an interface definition language (IDL). Corba's IDL allows you to declare objects & interfaces in a language neutral way. These idl files are then run through an IDL compiler which outputs the appropriate classes, headers, stubs, proxies etc. for the language of your choice.

For example [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/) is an implementation of Corba for C#. I have no idea how good it is, but it would have an IDL compiler that spits out C# classes. Java has an IDL compiler called idlj as part of the JDK.

In theory therefore you could have C# and Java implemented from the same interfaces & classes.

Another way of doing something similar would be to utilise a UML tool that can generate source code from a model.

Another alternative would be to use something like WSDL / XSD to define your interfaces & types, and generate stubs from that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/). With it, you can write your program in Java (or a JVM language) and transform it into a .NET assembly. So you'll have both a JVM and a .NET version of your program.